# Can 宁和 be used as a real name

Tags: grammar, meaning, character-identification

I'm creating a half Japanese half Chinese character and I'm trying to figure out whether or not 宁和 can be used as a name. I'm also wondering if it means to aspire to peace and is read a "ninghe".

Comment: 宁和 (Níng hé)  is ok. as a name, One thing though, it sounds quite similar to Japan's new 年號 (reign title) 令和 (Lìng hé)

Comment: both 宁 and 和 mean peace, there's no 'aspire' part if that's what you mean

Comment: 郁宁？（yu4ning2）探宁（tan4ning2）玄宁（xuan2ning2）They are closer to "aspire and peace"(´▽｀)ノ♪

Answer (score 2):

宁和 can be used as a real Chinese name. 宁 is a common family name and 和 is totally ok for a given name.

When used as a family name, 宁 pronounced as ning4. With such pronunciation, it also can mean "rather", like 宁死不屈(rather die than surrender).

When pronounced as ning2, it means quiet/peace.

To be clear, people will say ning4和 but won't understand the name as "rather peace". Usually, this name will be considered as "quiet and peace". It is a valid name but won't have the "aspire" to peace.

All the above is for Chinese name, not quite sure if it is allowed to only have 2 characters in Japanese name.

Comment: Almost no one cares about the meaning of the family name unless the full name is a commonly used word. However, that is the case parents usually want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use 和宁 with your surname, example: 王和宁